# Making an easy way of getting the value I need in PHP?

Tags: php

I am making a game in php as a personal project.

I can make items out of items that I have, the items I have are stored in an array called `$user`

For now I am displaying how many of each item I can make by doing the following (let us say that to make a spade you need 1 wood and 1 metal and 1 energy)

```
$amount = min($user['wood'], $user['metal'], $user['energy']);
// USER HAS ITEMS TO MAKE SPADE
if ($amount) {
     echo '<form class="spacerTop" action="#" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="itemPlus" value="spade" />
     <select name="amount">';
     $i = 1;
     while ($i <= $amount) {
          echo '<option value"' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
     ++$i;
     }
     echo '</select>
     <input type="submit" value="Make Spades" />
     </form>';
}
```

Doing the above will only show the option to make a spade if the user has the minimum amount of items to make a spade. It will also show in a `form select` how many spades they can make in total using the `min` value from php.

What I cannot work out is say if it costs 2 energy, 10 wood and 5 metal? How can I get the same functionality as above even if the items it costs to make an item differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$amount = floor(min($user['wood'] / 2, $user['metal'] / 5, $user['energy'] / 10));
```

This will give you the maximum amount of "stuff" given the requirements. A special case is where all divisors are 1 (then you don't have to call `floor` to round down the number).

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat, I had worked out the divide bit but it was floor that now makes it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store the requirements in an array. $requirements[item][need]
2. Calculate `floor($user['wood']/$requirements['spade']['wood'])` and so on
3. Take the minimum of these. That is how much they can make.

Comment: This wouldn't work I don't think as the requirement would be 2 and say the user has 200 wood, it would be 2 / 200 which would be 0.002